# jQuery Lazy plugin doesn't work on jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, lazy-loading

i need lazy load on my jquery mobile page. I use http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/ ,but images doesn't load. Example is [here](http://newm.loupak.cz/video/obrazky/20699-obrazky-pro-dnesni-den-826-dil?limit=-15) Where is the problem? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: replace `data-src=""` with `src=""`.

Comment: Try http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt (it is listed on http://jquerymobile.com/resources/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from top of HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on("pageinit", function() {
      jQuery("img.lazy").lazy();
   });
</script>
```

Place this near bottom of HTML

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("img.lazy").lazy();
});
```

pageinit has been deprecated in 1.4.0 in favor of pagecreate. It is triggered on the page being initialized,

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly it doesn't help.

Comment: `.ready()` shouldn't be used in jQM; `pagecreate` is the correct event.